# phpmailer, client not responding to server

Tags: phpmailer, gmail-api

When trying to send an email through the phpmailer nothing happens. After looking at the log it seems that when the server asks for XOAUTH2 the client simply doesn't respond... Usually the client would send the XOAUTH2 authorisation

```
2020-09-09 21:14:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP p9sm413427wma.42 - gsmtp

2020-09-09 21:14:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 'website'

2020-09-09 21:14:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, ['ip']250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8

2020-09-09 21:14:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS

2020-09-09 21:14:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS

2020-09-09 21:14:20 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 'website'

2020-09-09 21:14:20 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, ['ip']250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
```

This suddenly stopped working recently for an unknown reason. Nothing has been altered on my end to cause this to occur.

Does anyone have any idea about what could be causing this?

Comment: I've not seen that – I'd recommend tracing that in a debugger to see what it's hanging up on. The server doesn't *ask* for auth, it just waits for whatever command the client wants to send, however, here it looks like the end of the previous EHLO response (`250 SMTPUTF8`) is not being detected for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems it was an outdated refresh token.
Odd that no error was appearing in debug mode though